# How to disable the SwipeRefresh during FastScrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am implementing `SwipeRefresh` in my `ListView`. Its working fine when i pull the `ListView` down. But whenever i scroll down using `fastScroll`, it still `swipes` the list. How can i disable this `SwipeRefresh` when i am `fastScrolling` the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement

- **`yourListView.setOnScrollListener(...)`**

in which you will implement

- **`onScrollStateChange`**

where u will enable and disable the swipe refresh while scrolling.